# spring data neo4j (SDN4) - find by relationship

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I'm studying spring data for Neo4J and I've seen some examples where you just define a method in the repository interface following some standards (to find by a specific attribute) and it's automatically handled by spring. Ex: findByName.

It works quite straightforward with basic attributes but it doesn't seems to work when the attribute is actually a relationship.

See this example:

```
public class AcceptOrganizationTask extends AbstractTask {
    @Relationship(type="RELATES_TO", direction = "OUTGOING")
    private OrganizationInvite invitation;
    ...
}
```

In the repository interface I've defined 3 methods (All with the same goal):

```
List<AcceptOrganizationTask> findAllByInvitation(OrganizationInvite invite);

    @Query("MATCH (i:OrganizationInvite)<-[RELATES_TO]-(t:AcceptOrganizationTask) WHERE i={invite} RETURN t")
List<AcceptOrganizationTask> getTaskByInvitation(@Param("invite") OrganizationInvite invite);

AcceptOrganizationTask findByInvitation_Id(Long invitationId);
```

None of them are able to retrieve the task by its invite property. But if I use use findAll() I can get the object with the property associated to the correct invitation.

Am I missing something ?

Bellow I have the Cypher code generated for this three methods:

**findAllByInvitation**

```
MATCH (n:`AcceptOrganizationTask`) 
   WHERE n.`invitation` = { `invitation_0` } 
   WITH n MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) RETURN p, ID(n) 
   with params {invitation_0={entityId=15, version=0, createdOn=1484758262374, lastChanged=1484758262374, createUser=null, lastUpdatedBy=null, email=user2@acme.com, randomKey=fc940b14-12c3-4894-b2b4-728e3a6b8036, invitedUser={entityId=11, version=0, createdOn=1484758261450, lastChanged=1484758261450, createUser=null, lastUpdatedBy=null, name=User user2@acme.com, email=user2@acme.com, credentialsNonExpired=true, lastPasswordResetDate=null, authorities=null, authoritiesInDB=[], accountNonExpired=true, accountNonLocked=true, enabled=true, id=11}, id=15}}
```

**getTasksByInvitation**

```
MATCH (i:OrganizationInvite)<-[RELATES_TO]-(t:AcceptOrganizationTask)
WHERE i={invite} RETURN t with params {invite=15}
```

**findByInvitation_Id**

```
MATCH (n:`AcceptOrganizationTask`) 
MATCH (m0:`OrganizationInvite`) 
   WHERE m0.`id` = { `invitation_id_0` } 
MATCH (n)-[:`RELATES_TO`]->(m0) 
WITH n 
   MATCH p=(n)-[*0..1]-(m) RETURN p, ID(n) 
with params {invitation_id_0=15}
```

All entities inherit from a common AbstractEntity with and Long id field, annotated with @GraphId.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment derived finder queries support only works to one level of nesting.

We are hoping to add this feature soon in the coming weeks though.

For now you can write a custom `@Query` to get around this.